# Print Javascript only after popup launched

Tags: javascript, jquery, popup

I am trying to modify this exit intent popup script. I want to a line of javascript to only work if the exit intent popup is launched. The line of javascript is simple. Something like this:

```
<script data-cfasync="false" type="text/javascript" src="http://www.tradeadexchange.com/a/display.php"></script>
```

I tried placing this code inside the popup but it still works even if the popup is not launched. I wold like it to only work if the popup is launched.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the `onleave` callback of the plugin

Something like this

```
$.glue({
    onleave: function(e) {
        $.getScript('http://www.tradeadexchange.com/a/display.php');
    }
});
```